# On HPUX, how do I list the full path to the executable for all running processes?

Tags: unix, hp-ux

What I need: A list of all currently running executables with their full path.

Something like this:

```
1234 /full/path/to/executable
4567 /full/path/to/executable2
```

Using `UNIX95= ps -exo pid,comm` I can get a list with PIDs and the commands like this

```
11146 /opt/wbem/lbin/cimprovagt 0 4 8 root IOTreeModule
8338 /opt/ssh/libexec/sftp-server
16684 postgres: sfmdb evweb [local] idle
2518 /usr/sbin/stm/uut/bin/tools/monitor/WbemWrapperMonitor
2264 /usr/sbin/psb/bin/diagtxd
8340 -sh
7772 sshd: root@pts/0
8333 sshd: root@pts/1
7777 /opt/ssh/libexec/sftp-server
```

This is as close I've managed to get using `ps`, but it is not good enough:

- Some lines do not include the full path (apparently because they are not started using the full path).
- Extra data after the executable name (I need to support executables with spaces in their name so I can't just split the string)

As such, I've concluded that `ps` won't get me all the way.

Is there an equivalent to Linux's /proc where /proc/{pid}/exe points to the executable? If not, is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pfiles <pid>` can list the full path to the executable.

Example:

Snippet from `UNIX95=1 ps -efo pid,comm`

```
 1666 cimprovagt
```

Now lets run `pfiles 1666`

```
1666:                   /opt/wbem/lbin/cimprovagt
0: S_ISCHR mode:666 dev:64,3 ino:124 uid:2 gid:2 rdev:3,2
flags = O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE
file  = /dev/null
```

The first line shows the full path to executable. This is good enough for my purposes.